# Parse query whereKey from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a Parse class with the name "Question", and a column called "quizid" of type Number.

In xcode swift class, I have a variable of type Int quiz_id.

I have a class inherited from PFQueryTableViewController

I want to pull data from the class "Question" based on where condition that column "quizid" value is equal to, quiz_id integer variable.

Here is the code I am using, but It gives runtime exception. 
Could you tell me the right code for query?
whereKey while using Int variable in swift

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Question")
    query.whereKey("quizid", equalTo:PFObject(withoutDataWithObjectId:self.quiz_id! as! String))
    query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")

    return query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check for **Optional()** by printing your value. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, I should just use,

```
query.whereKey("quizid", equalTo: self.quiz_id!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the equalTo: expect a String and don't a PFobject..
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-basic-queries

try

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{
let query = PFQuery(className: "Question")
query.whereKey("quizid", equalTo:PFObject(withoutDataWithObjectId:self.quiz_id! as! String) as! String
query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
return query
}
```